# Is it correct question "Is doing something does another thing"?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

Is it correct question "Is doing something does another thing", like

"Is eating vegetables does good for my health?" or negative

"Ins't eating vegetables does good for my health?"

I found myself saying sentences like these but now I think I might be using two auxiliary verbs with one subject which is probably wrong and

"Isn't eating vegetables good for my health?" or

"Does eating vegetables do good for my health?" would be more correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not correct.

The equivalent statement would be

> Eating vegetables is does good for my health.

I hope you can see why that is incorrect.

A correct statement would be

> Eating vegetables is good for my health.

And so the question would be formed by inversion:

> Is eating vegetables good for my health?

Similarly it would be possible to say

> Eating vegetables does do good for my health.

And you could invert the verb to make that a question.  If you are confused about the grammar in a question, it is often easier to analyse the statement.  If the statement is not grammatically correct, then the question formed from it can't be correct.